# Android Emulator window not displaying properly

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am very new to android development. I have issues in Android AVD device display. It display the content very big. Here I cannot attach screenshot.

- The lock screen looks like the very big font for Time and Date which
  beyond the screen size.
- Even I cannot see the lock icon to go to Home screen.

**Device Definition:**

- Device : Nexus One(3.7", 480 x 800:hdpi)
- Target : Android 5.1.1 - API Level 22,
- CPU / ABI : ARM (armeabi - v7a),
- SKIN : WVGA800,
- RAM : 512 ,
- VM Heap: 32 ,
- Internal : 1024

  I already searched for fix and deleted device and recreated the device, but same problem. But I cannot find the solution.

  Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not the solution but can you try one thing can you change the device from Nexus One to Nexus 4 or 5 atleast.

Comment: Use Genymotion Android Vm: https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/download

Comment: I will try both. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a AVD having below configuration.
It is very fast for testing application.

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found that **Device** and **Skin** selection is somewhat an issue with newer Android SDK(not in 24.2.0 and lower, tested 24.4.1, 25.2.5 and has this issue). When I choose any *named* **Device** like Nexus *, then I have to choose only skin **Skin with dynamic hardware controls** and if I choose *unnamed* **Device**(with only size and resolution mentioned) then I can choose any of the **Skin** in the list.

Screenshot of how the problem is looking is at https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96949/android-avd-not-displaying-appropriate-scale

Answer (score 0):

if you match your laptop/computer resolution to your external monitor's resolution. Then you can return back to your PC's resolution.

On you laptop/Computer From Settings -> Display settings -> Decrease the screen layout (125%) or decrease the scale and layout of your screen and restart emulator.
[This is how to change  display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3AeD.png)

before result
[Before changing the display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu2rk.png)
after result
[After changing the display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0OzA.png)

P.S.It's temporary solution.